# How to communicate between two different perspective of eclipse in java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating a custom perspective in eclipse. What I need is, I want to send an object from a perspective to my newly created custom perspective. Is there any way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: You don't 'send objects to a perspective'. Views and editors access objects from some sort of model objects such as the file system, a database, .... [edit] your question and describe in details what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thanks for replying.. 
In my case I need to send an object to the perspective.
What happens is, in old perspective, there is one button, On click of that  button I am opening a new perspective. Now in the new Perspective some objects are getting populated and now I want to send these objects to the old perspective. How should I do it.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'sending an object to a perspective' so I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In e4, you can use the "e4 event system": https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html

You can synchronously or asynchronously send an event with parameters and declare listeners that will react to the event

In the class that sends the "event":

```
@Inject IEventBroker eventBroker;
eventBroker.post(<topic>,<data>); //Asynchronous
eventBroker.send(<topic>,<data>); //Synchronous
```

In the class that will listen to the event:

```
@Inject @Optional
private void whateverName(final @UIEventTopic(<topic>) <data type> <data name>) {
   ...
}
```

On the receiving side, you can separate the method that will "build" the part from the method that will "populate/refresh" the data in the part, the one with the listener